# Что такое "задор"?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Когда мы говорим, что дело сделано идеально, то употребляем поговорку "без сучка без задоринки" (сомневаюсь: нужна ли тут запятая?). То есть, в данном случае "задоринка" - это нечто вроде заусенца, неровности, огреха обработки поверхности.
В то же время задорным мы называем веселого человека, энергичного оптимиста.
Честно говоря, не вижу связи между двумя этими понятиями. Что же изначально означало слово "задор" и какое из значений первично: веселье или заусенец?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Происхождение "задоринки" понятно: оно очевидно восходит к "задирать", связано с плотницкими работами и означает неровности, царапины и всё такое прочее. Слово "задирать" и его производные развились и в переносном значении: "задирать" – это раздражать кого-то, цеплять, а "задор" – это соответствующее качество (состояние) человека. Задорный человек – это тот, который раздражает (обычно в хорошем смысле), выводит всех из равновесия, цепляет, заводит и так далее.

Более подробно можно прочитать у Виноградова: http://wordhist.narod.ru/zador.html

Comment: Из серии "улыбайтесь - это всех раздражает")))))